# Making AdMob work on Android 2.3 device?

Tags: android, admob

Ok so I've read a lot of articles, questions and answers but still can't find one that works for me...

I'm trying to show an AdMob banner in an Android app.
I'm using Eclipse and the latest AdMob SDK (4.3.1), which requires Android 3.2 (13) to work.
Thing is, my test device is only 2.3.3 (10).

--

The best I've got so far is the app compiling against Android 2.3.3, running on the device, and a banner showing up but with this message: `You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges`...

In this case, the configChanges attributes is set to `"keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"`
If I change it for the "full" version (with the addition of `"|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`), it doesn't compile anymore, as these params require Android 3.2.

--

I've read that it is possible to compile against Android SDK 13 while keeping 10 as the `minSdkVersion`. I've tried that, the configChanges attribute is now full and does not generate an error, but Eclipse now shows my device as not compatible with 3.2, and the app crashes if I run it anyway.

--

But obviously people seem to get AdMob working on older devices, no? So, how?

If AdMob 4.3.1 requires at least Android 3.2 no matter what, is there an older version that's compatible with 2.3?

I'm really confused here...
Thanks to anyone who will be able to shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>
```

works for me with admob 4.1.1, haven't tried 4.3.1 yet.

Comment: I've finally found a 4.1.1 AdMob jar (no way to get it from Google Code ><') and you're right, it works, without the extra configChanges. Huge thanks to you!

Now I guess I can stick to this version, maybe it's the last compatible one for Android 2.3... But in this case, why wouldn't Google let us have access to earlier versions of AdMob for compatibility?

Comment: Where did you get hold of that? I'm facing the same problem. It's lunacy that Google should prevent Admob working for the majority of Android devices.

Comment: I had it with my Galileo version, but since I've upgraded to Indigo i have the same issue. I'm just using the compatibility kit and targeting API 13

Comment: I had the same problem, used this solution.
Anyway I also made a copy of the JAR in case someone is looking for it here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/453866/permanent/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar

I would like to know if there is another solution, I agree with Jim that somehow it doesn't make sense that AdMob doesn't support the majority of Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

Set `android:targetSdkVersion to 13 and  android:minSdkVersion to 3 then the adMob will run on all devices equal and greater than 1.5